# Looping through DirectoryEntry or any object hierarchy - C#

Tags: c#, loops, hierarchy, web-crawler, directoryservices

I am currently developing an application that use the System.DirectoryServices namespace to create a DirectoryEntry object and loop through the entire hierarchy to collect information.

I do not know number of child entries for each DirectoryEntry object in the hierarchy, so I can not create a N number of nested loops to spiders through the Children property

Here is my pseudo code example:

```
//root directory
DirectoryEntry root = new DirectoryEntry(path);

if(DirectoryEntry.Childern != null)
{
    foreach(DirectoryEntry child in root.Children)
    {
        //loop through each Children property unitl I reach the last sub directory
    }
}
```

My question is, what is the best way to create a loop to collect information if you so not know the number of sub directories in your object?

(This can be applied to any type of object that you do not know the object hierarchy)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a recursive function if you don't know the depth of the hierarchy and need to traverse down through all levels.
Below is an example using depth-first traversal.

```
using (DirectoryEntry root = new DirectoryEntry(someDN))
{
    DoSomething(root);
}


function DoSomething(DirectoryEntry de)
{
    // Do some work here against the directory entry

    if (de.Children != null)
    {
        foreach (DirectoryEntry child in de.Children)
        {
            using (child)
            {
                DoSomething(child);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively, without recursion, you can do a traversal by adding a Queue or Stack data structure and storing the objects you've seen but havent visited yet.

```
Queue<DirectoryEntry> queue = new Queue<DirectoryEntry>();
DirectoryEntry root = new DirectoryEntry(someDN);
queue.Add(root);

while (queue.Any())
{
    using (DirectoryEntry de = queue.Dequeue())
    {
        // Do some work here against the directory entry

        if (de.Children != null)
        {
            foreach (DirectoryEntry child in de.Children)
            {
                queue.Enqueue(child);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This, btw, is a good example of where recursion is actually a good way to handle a problem.  Because the file system itself imposes depth limitations, you shouldn't blow the stack.  You have to be careful, however, in case there is a loop in the tree do to links...

Comment: @jeffmaphone: DirectoryEntry actually is going to be pointing at an LDAP server, not the file system. I'm not sure about the LDAP depth limits but if there are loops, the easiest way to handle it is to record the GUID of each entry you visit and stop recursing if you visit the same entry twice.

Comment: Use `using(child){...}`within the foreach-loop to be sure to clean up after yourself. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41378746/disposing-during-foreach/41378945#41378945

Comment: @Born2Smile Good point. Updated the code sample here with proper disposal.

Answer (score 2):

You have to write recursive function as...

```
DirectoryEntry root = new DirectoryEntry(path);
DoForEveryNode(root);

void DoForEveryNode(DirectoryEntry node)
{
    // do something..

    foreach(DirectoryEntry child in node.Children)
    {
        DoForEveryNode(child);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a function which recursively calls itself on the children.
 exit condition: no more children etc..

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use Recursion. Set that code up in a function that then calls itself inside the foreach loop, passing the next directory (child item) each time

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the wonderful world of recursion.  You need a function that accepts a Directory as an argument.  Given that directory, it looks up all of the child directories and for each one... calls itself.