# Disposing during foreach

Tags: c#, active-directory, resource-cleanup

In this question:
[Looping through DirectoryEntry or any object hierarchy - C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/706460/looping-through-directoryentry-or-any-object-hierarchy-c-sharp#)

The suggested answer for traversing an LDAP tree is to

```
DirectoryEntry root = new DirectoryEntry(someDN);

DoSomething(root);

function DoSomething(DirectoryEntry de){
    // Do some work here against the directory entry
    if (de.Children != null) {
        foreach (DirectoryEntry child in de.Children) {
            DoSomething(child);
        }
    }
}
```

My Question is: Do you need to call Dispose() on each child at the end of each iteration? or will the foreach-loop handle the necessary calls to Dispose()? or are they simply not necessary in a foreach-loop (because perhaps the loop re-uses the resources one would otherwise want to Dispose())

Comment: I believe it re-uses child in each loop, since a memory allotted won't be having a reference after re-assigning, it gets disposed. But I'm not sure whether it happens exactly like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you need to call `Dispose` on every child. When you call `Children` property of `DirectoryEntry`, it actually creates new `DirectoryEntries` instance. When you enumerate over that instance, it pulls child entries one by one (not all of them at once), and it will not `Dispose` them (nor anything will reuse them). Since `DirectoryEntry` is basically COM object - it's quite important to dispose it (it hold unmanaged resources). So correct way is something like this:

```
function DoSomething(DirectoryEntry de){
    // Do some work here against the directory entry
    if (de.Children != null) {
        foreach (DirectoryEntry child in de.Children) {
            using (child) {
                DoSomething(child);
            }
        }
    }
}
```